# Where do benchmark tests go?

Tags: rust

Where in the project structure do benchmark tests for a library go? I tried putting them in a file in the tests folder of the library and they fail to run when running `cargo bench`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for Cargo's project layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) says:

> Benchmarks go in the `benches` directory.

That's the convention, but in your Cargo.toml [you can configure targets](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#configuring-a-target), and one of those is the `[[bench]]` target. Doing that will let you place them wherever you'd like.